# How does a screen display a higher resolution than its physical resolution?

Tags: display, resolution

My MacBook Air screen has a 2560 x 1600 physical resolution but using some software i.e. EasyRes, my screen is allowed to display resolutions lower than 2560 x 1600.

According to my limited knowledge, this is possible when multiple hardware pixels are mapped into one logical pixel to display a lower resolution. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

However, my screen is allowed to also display higher resolutions than my native resolution  i.e. higher than 2560 x 1600.

How is this possible when my physical resolution is only 2560 x 1600? How can my screen show, say 2880 x 1800 pixels when there are only 2560 x 1600 hardware pixels available?

A high level answer of this process is appreciated.

Comment: Pictures can be scaled down as well as up. Your screen may physically only able to show 2560x1600 but if you render at a higher resolution and scale it down you can get more detail than you would at native resolution. The PS5 for example almost always targets 4K resolution even on HD displays because you get better antialiasing and scene detail even when scaled down.

Comment: "render at a higher resolution and scale it down you can get more detail than you would at native resolution", does this preserve the relative size of elements in the image? For example, if you render the letter "A" in a higher resolution and it occupies say 15% of the whole image then you downscale it to fit a smaller resolution screen, will it also occupy 15% of the whole image (in the smaller resolution screen)?

Comment: I have moved my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The increase in render resolution versus actual native resolution is a form of anti-aliasing. It is typically known as [Supersampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersampling).

Your screen may physically only able to show 2560x1600 but if you render at a higher resolution and scale it down you can get more detail than you would at native resolution. The PS5 for example almost always targets 4K resolution even on HD displays because you get better anti-aliasing and scene detail even when scaled down.

In theory you would render everything at a scale with a ratio equivalent to the increase from the lower to higher resolution, then scale it down to native resolution. Doing this has a cost in that you are doing more work in rendering at a higher resolution, which needs more RAM, and then scaling it down, which requires more processing power, but this is often easily achieved by modern graphics cards.

What happens is that you end up with elements that are the exact same size as they would be if you rendered at the native resolution, but everything ends up being slightly "filtered" and softened by the scaling.

It reduces harsh lines to a more subtle blend in edges that can be more aestetically pleasing at the cost of needing more computation. This is a somewhat extreme example but you can see the effect it can have on the edges of lines that would otherwise look somewhat jagged. [(From Wikipedia)](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Anti-aliasing.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I understand most parts of it. The only question left is that when increasing resolution from 2560 x 1600 (native) to 2880 x 1800, the text and icons become smaller. (The quality of the text and icons seems to be the exact same as well when I zoom in to view the pixels)


Does this mean there is no scaling involved when rendering at different resolutions? i.e. rendering an "A" uses the same number of pixels both in 2560 x 1600 and 2880 x 1800. Hence scaling it down to fit the native screen causes the text and icons to be smaller. Is my idea correct?

Comment: For clarity:
Text and icon at 2560 x 1600: https://imgur.com/IrAB0ez, at 2880 x 1800: https://imgur.com/Vl4LQCw. (If you compare closely, the text and icon size in 2880x1800 is smaller)
But the quality is the same on both resolutions: https://imgur.com/HeEtKVD

Comment: It depends. It is entirely possible to just render at the higher resolution and skip scaling up UI features so that you end up with a larger "virtual" desktop size, it would then get scaled down to the native display resolution and so end up being smaller.